# HTML minifier puts every tag on a new line

Tags: php, html, minify

I am using a html minifier, which can be found here: [HTML minify](https://github.com/mrclay/minify/blob/master/min/lib/Minify/HTML.php)

The strange thing to me is that every tag is placed on a new line. Is this common behavior or am I doing something wrong. The output looks something like this:

[image: Output from html minify]

Anyone know how I can fix this so that is just creates one line of code, or is has this was of minifying some advantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked the code?

```
// use newlines before 1st attribute in open tags (to limit line lengths)
        $this->_html = preg_replace('/(<[a-z\\-]+)\\s+([^>]+>)/i', "$1\n$2", $this->_html);
```

Long lines can be a bad bad thing - browsers might fill buffers or just drop stuff at the end of the line. So it looks like that Minify script has it hard coded in, with no options to change. So if you really want it all on one line, just customise your version to not do that replacement. Open Source win.

Comment: I did check the code, but regex is just a black box for me, after all the years I still don't understand it. Nice point about the browsers and long lines, I had no idea. I think ill just keep it like this.

Comment: Oh I see it was even commented in, I did not see that. Sorry!

Comment: "Long lines can be a bad bad thing - browsers might fill buffers or just drop stuff at the end of the line." - Do you have any references for that or is it just a thought? Seems like non-sense to me..